# what is the equivalent of CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS in postresql

Tags: database, postgresql

I want to do something like

```
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS complete_user_profile ...
```

not sure how though

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You could use [`CREATE OR REPLACE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createview.html):

> CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW is similar, but if a view of the same name already exists, it is replaced. The new query must generate the same columns that were generated by the existing view query (that is, the same column names in the same order and with the same data types), but it may add additional columns to the end of the list. The calculations giving rise to the output columns may be completely different.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW complete_user_profile ...
```

Comment: I thought so but I found it kind of counterintuitive and idiomatic the fact that you have to imply that you are changing the underlying query. thnx

Comment: @LetsPlayYahtzee: there is a difference between `create if not exists` and `create or replace` - for a view `create or replace` makes much more sense

Comment: You may not want to replace the view e.g. if you're running through a migration script.